# Draw/generate list of polylines from list of unordered points

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry

I already had a list of coordinate of points received from many cars on streets in a specific area. Is there any algorithm to draw the list of appropriate polylines which represent for streets that cars have passed from that list of points?

[EDIT]

For example, the picture bellow is a set of points coordinates received from cars on streets.
[List of points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgcUw.png)

The expected result I want is the list of polylines (list of ordered points) like this (6 polylines in this example). [Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47wdt.png).

Example result data: [line1: [(lat1, ln1), (lat2, ln2), (lat3, ln3),...], line2: [(lat1, ln1), (lat2, ln2), (lat3, ln3),...]]

It means by some how, I have to connect all the unordered points to make polylines or draw polylines that represent for (almost) the points they cross.

I have tried k-means algorithm to group the points, then connected the points in each one together. My thinking is all the points within a cluster belong to 1 polyline. But the problems are I don't know how many "k" clusters It should be and how to choose the most potential centroids to make the result accurate. Therefore, I tried to generate a pretty big number (exg: 300) of random centroids. Eventually, there are many clusters just had 1 point (the centroid and the member point are identical). In the other hand, when it's lesser number of centroid, the clusters is not accurate like I expected (the points in one cluster belong to many polylines).

In some articles I've researched, there are some talk about "Points To Line" function of "arcGIS" (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Points_To_Line/00170000003s000000/). I've never heard about this before so I really don't know if it can be used with java

Comment: Please narrow down your question. Show some example data and the result what you want to get. What are your thoughts on solving this problem?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have edit my question to make it clear. If you want to know more info, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Solving this in the most general case is very hard.

The easiest thing you can do is to connect each point to its nearest neighbour. If the points are sufficiently close to each other, it should work OK.

If you want something more advanced, I would look at fitting a spline to the data, as in [this Matlab article](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/224704-fitting-smooth-closed-spline-to-scattered-2d-points).

Trying to cluster the data would not be my first option, but if you want a clustering algorithm without the need for prior knowledge of the number of clusters, take look at [Mean shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_shift).

Comment: Like you said connecting each point to its nearest neighbor is simple and works pretty well. However, of course, It does not warrant the accuracy in the most general case. Anyway I will take a look your suggested articles and continue to figure out the better approach. Many thanks for those and your answer.